# Get notified when NSDocument is saved

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, autosave

How can I get notified when `NSDocument` is saved, the first time and subsequent times?

I first thought that overriding `writeToURL:ofType:error:` would do it, but it appears that this method is also called for temporary autosaves before the document is saved for the first time, and maybe on copy/duplicate operations.

On the other hand, `setFileURL:` appears to be called the first time that the document is saved but not on subsequent times.

Is there some kind of Save notification? Or do I have to work around the various border cases of the above methods?

Comment: Is there anything interesting about the url given for the temporary autosaves that would let you distinguish?

Comment: @occulus Yes, but as far as I know it might change in different OS versions and/or configurations.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDocument` has [writeSafelyToURL::::](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsdocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/writeSafelyToURL%3aofType%3aforSaveOperation%3aerror%3a), which in addition to the target location URL also gets a NSSaveOperationType passed in.
This would allow you to filter out autosave operations.

Don't forget to call the super implementation when overriding `writeSafelyToURL`.